# Too many objects need random emission values

Tags: materials, objects, light

I'm new to blender, and am working on a large "cyberpunk" skyscraper that needs a ton of windows. I applied some basic materials nodes that randomized the emission values to each window as a separate object, which works great. [image: The nodes I used] [image: A small part of the building]

However, the problem is that the picture shown is only a small fraction of the building, and when I'm putting the parts of the building together, the object count is reaching the thousands, and my computer slows to a crawl. Is there possibly an alternative to randomize whether each window is on or off that will remain once I combine them into a single object, or at least in bigger pieces? Maybe have each window be randomly assigned one of two materials? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If it is just squares why not use a Bricks texture instead?

Comment: If you found a solution, please write it on the answers section so that other users with a similar question can learn from your experience. Read:
[Can I answer my own question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestion, but I figured out a different way to tackle the problem. I made all of the windows all as a separate object, and I discovered the random selection tool and randomly selected individual faces to be assigned to emission material